# Error with Chart.js : TypeError: t is undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I keep getting this error and I wasn't able to display a Chart.js chart yet, although I have tried multiples codes I found on the internet.

Here is the relevant part of the HTML :

```
<head>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id = "myChart"></canvas>
    ...
</body>
```

Here is the javascript :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I found that example here : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

And I get this error in the console :

```
TypeError: t is undefined
```

Can someone help please ? Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bd6Lf88a/ The problem must be somewhere else. Scratch that; you need to include the latest version: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.js`

Comment: Yes just figured that at the moment. Apparently there are many versions on that CDN that don't work. This one https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.0/Chart.min.js apparently works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Solved, apparently the script link I was using was bugged. Changed it to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js and it works fine. See `Chris G`'s comment.

Answer (score 2):

Put the javascript code (start with `<script type="text/javascript">var ctx ...</script>`) after the canvas element. This ensures that the canvas element is already present at the time when it gets referenced by `var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");`

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2.8.0 (current latest).  Earlier versions as suggested here did not help.

The solution to this error for me was providing the correct element ID for the context.  I was giving `new Chart()` "chartjs-1" because I blindly copied an example, but my canvas ID was "myCanvas".  Giving `new Chart()` the actual ID of my canvas fixed the problem.

Note, the error in the question is from Firefox.  Chrome gave a different error that clued me into the real culprit:  `Cannot read property 'length' of null`